# Using GitHub API to retrieve files with specific extension

Tags: javascript, github

I want to get a list of files from given git repository. For an example, I want to get all *.js files from a given git repository. How can I use GitHub API to satisfy above requirement?  or is there any way to get the list of *.js files from a git repository?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here, what I did to find out all **.js** file in my own repository.

```
curl -i "https://api.github.com/search/code?q=extension:js+repo:vnation/NewsAggregator"
```

source: https://developer.github.com/v3/search/#search-code

**EDIT**

This is what I did to find out the path of ".classpath" file in the master branch of my repo.

```
curl -i "https://api.github.com/repos/vnation/NewsAggregator/contents/.classpath"
```

SOURCE: https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/contents/#get-contents

> **However**, git response above API with base64 encoded content. So, to get raw data you should use **below** one.

```
curl -i "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/vnation/NewsAggregator/master/.classpath"
```

Comment: Thanks. It works. can we use GitHub API to read a file content in repo temporary? That means if I want to get a list of dependencies mentioned in package.json file, can I read the package.json file using GitHub API?