# GitHub API find all files with extension

Tags: github, github-api

I want to get links of all GitHub files with specific extension. I found out that I can use `extension:bin` to search for all `*.bin` files, URL https://github.com/search?q=extension%3Abin&type=Code

I found [Using GitHub API to retrieve files with specific extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48191942/using-github-api-to-retrieve-files-with-specific-extension)
but this answer deals with specific repository.

Update: I was trying https://api.github.com/search/code?q=extension:ifc+size:1000..1500 but response is

```json
{
    "message": "Validation Failed",
    "errors": [
        {
            "message": "Must include at least one user, organization, or repository",
        }
    ]
}
```

Do we have a method in GitHub API to search in all repositories? I didn't find here https://docs.github.com/en/rest/search#search-code

Comment: I’m guessing they restrict that api to specific things as it’s likely costly to run

Comment: Thank you, I am looking for  answer based on official sources

Comment: @davidfong i just want to understand is it possible to solve my task with help of github API

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Root cause analysis

I have reproduced the issue by performing an HTTP request without the authorization header:

```bash
$ curl \
    --request GET \
    --header 'Accept: application/vnd.github+json' \
    'https://api.github.com/search/code?q=extension:ifc+size:1000..1500'
{
  "message": "Validation Failed",
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "Must include at least one user, organization, or repository",
      "resource": "Search",
      "field": "q",
      "code": "invalid"
    }
  ],
  "documentation_url": "https://docs.github.com/v3/search/"
}
```

### Root cause

Therefore, it looks like you have missed the authorization header.

## Solution

Perform an HTTP request with the appropriate authorization header.

### Draft example command line

```bash
curl \
    --request GET \
    --header 'Accept: application/vnd.github+json' \
    --header 'Authorization: Bearer <TOKEN>' \
    'https://api.github.com/search/code?q=extension:ifc+size:1000..1500'
```

The example command line has worked fine (returned search results) for me.

Please, replace `<TOKEN>` with a GitHub personal access token.

## Additional references

- [Search: Search code - GitHub Docs](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/search#search-code).
- Question. [How to search for code in GitHub with GitHub API? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24132790/how-to-search-for-code-in-github-with-github-api).